# Meteor JS: How to expire mongo data automatically?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Is there a way to configure a collection in MongoDb to automatically expire from MeteorJS? I've seen how to do it from the [Mongo site](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/), but wasn't sure how to do this from Meteor:

```
  Tasks.insert({
    text: text,
    createdAt: new Date(),
  });

  //None of these work:
  Tasks.ensureIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 2 } );
  Tasks._ensureIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 2 } );
  Tasks.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 2 } );
```

Comment: Do you get any response from your calls to `ensureIndex`/`createIndex`? Can you inspect the `getIndexes()` output for your collection; Was the index created?

Comment: As a caveat, the TTL index drop will be performed by a different thread that will check once every minute or so - 2 seconds would work, but it might well over a minute until the data is actually deleted.

Comment: @Lix I don't think the indexes are being created - when I inspect the output after each of the above calls I always just get:

[
 {
  "v" : 1,
  "name" : "_id_",
  "key" : {
   "_id" : 1
  },
  "ns" : "meteor.tasks"
 }
]

Comment: @mnemosyn Ahh thanks that's useful to know - although I still think I'm not adding the TTL index properly... do you know the syntax that I should be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just remove it yourself? `insert`’s second parameter is a callback, inside which you can use `setTimeout` to wait 2 seconds:

```
Tasks.insert({
  text: text,
  createdAt: new Date(),
}, function(err, _id) {
  if (_id != null) {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
      Tasks.remove(_id);
    }, 2000); // 2 seconds delay
  }
});
```

Comment: I want the information to be expired regardless of whether the user's session is connected or not. My understanding here is a bit thin, but I thought that if I do this and the user closes their browser, this timeout won't fire?

Comment: The `insert` should happen on the server. You should be using a Meteor method (`Meteor.call('insertTask', someTask)`) to trigger a function to run on the server; inside that server-side function should be the code I wrote above. Assuming the server doesn’t crash, the timeout will fire. To be really safe, you could put some code inside your server-only `Meteor.startup` block that looks for and deletes tasks whose `createdAt` timestamps are more than 2 seconds old.

Comment: I don't know how meteor horizontal scaling works, but keep in mind that clocks aren't perfectly in sync.